# How to filter a range by first Character in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter a multipleColumnRange by column1 if a cell.Text starts with "A"

```
rng01.Columns(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="firstCharacter = 'A'", VisibleDropDown:=False
```

How could I do this, pls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

The first three lines were used for my test code.

```
Dim rng01 As Range
Set rng01 = [a1:c10]
rng01.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
rng01.Columns(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=A*", VisibleDropDown:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create an additional column with the first character of the words in column 1:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)
```

And filter on that new column.