# Delete dynamic number of rows between two variable string values?

Tags: excel

I have a file with too many variables for me to handle.  I want to delete all the rows between header rows (beginning with `H`), in a file.

Every header row has a consistent row after and before (T... after and E... before.)

I need to delete the row starting with `T` down to the row starting with `E`.

```
H100000

T100000

S100000

E100000

H100001

T100001

S100001

S100001

C100001

N100001

E100001

H100002

T100002

S100002

M100002

U100002

U100002

C100002

M100002

Y100002

E100002

H100003

T100003

S100003

N100003

E100003

H100004
```

If someone could assist with this I would be very grateful! I have gleaned the following form old posts on another site but the string qualifiers need to be exact. I can not get this to work with wildcards.

```
Sub DeletebyBookends()
Dim strStart As String, strEnd As String
Dim DELETEMODE As Boolean
Dim DelRng As Range
    strStart = "H100000"
    strEnd = "H100001"

    DELETEMODE = False
    For r = 1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'first to last used row

        If Range("C" & r).Value = strEnd Then DELETEMODE = False

        If DELETEMODE Then
            'Create a Delete Range that will be used at the end
            If DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = Range("A" & r)
            Else
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, Range("A" & r))
            End If
        End If

        If Range("C" & r).Value = strStart Then DELETEMODE = True
    Next r

    'Delete the Range compiled from above
    If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

Comment: It might be easier to think about extracting the rows that you want to keep rather than deleting the rows that you don't want.  Is there commonality between all of the rows you want to end up with (like they all start with H)?

Comment: Exactly that.  They all begin with an "H".

Comment: Check this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881214/how-to-filter-a-range-by-first-character-in-a-cell

Comment: If you use the autofilter method described in the above link, you could then copy visible cells only (ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy) to a new worksheet.

Comment: Worked great, thanks!  Man, was I over thinking thinking it!